# Raspberry Pi types in 'pi' but not the password 'raspberry' on login

Tags: boot, keyboard, password

I have only just received my Raspberry Pi and something has gone wrong. When I get to the stage of logging in my Pi types in 'pi' fine, but the password 'raspberry' does not type in.

The blinking dash: `_` stops for a sec when I type in a letter on the password stage as if it reconised me typing in something, but then it displays nothing. Is this normal? Am I not meant to see the password? Or is this an error?

Comment: See also: https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#generalPassword

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For security reasons, it is normal the password is hidden.

Please make sure you have a qwerty keyboard layout. In France, we have an azerty keyboard layout. So, to enter the password `raspberry`, we have to type `rqspberry`. To make sure you have the good keyboard layout, try to type the password in the user field **without validating it**.

Once you are logged in, you can [change the keyboard layout](http://elinux.org/RPi_Beginners#Keyboard_layout) by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and following the prompts. These instructions are for a Raspbian distro.

Comment: Yes, I do have a querty keyboard. So this was normal. Phew! I thought it was broken on the first day of going on it.

Answer (score -5):

You have to type the password in capitals to make it work . it worked for me so i hope it works for you.

Comment: This is not correct.