# using a SSH and can't login on my raspberry

Tags: raspbian, ssh, debian

I'm on a Mac and using Ethernet through a thunderbolt adapter. I use Raspbian Debian Wheezy 2014-09-09. I'm using VirtualBox (program) for school, and Cyberduck to setup the SSH connection. I'm supposed to use this method:

```
$ ssh -l pi 192.168.1.1
```

It will ask for my password, which is still the default. However, my computer won't recognize the Pi. 
I then used:

```
$ ssh -v pi 192.168.1.1
```

it showed this:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname pi: Name or service not known
```

**EDIT HERE**
Okay, so I followed a PDF from my school to set up a virtual machine. The program to make this is Virtualbox. That virtual machine runs on Debian. I've set up Debian and I was at the final step, giving the raspberry an IP address. I needed to shut off my ethernet cables ipv4 automatic configure and give the raspberry the ip address: 192.168.1.1. I did that with the code

`root@debianrouter:~# ssh -l pi 192.168.1.1`

than i get this:

`pi@192.168.1.1's password:`

I should be able to type the 
password: `raspberry`

Raspbian's default password but when I type that it doesn't work. I get this: `Permission denied, try again` and that's where I'm stuck. So I tried to get the debug things with

`root@debianrouter:~# ssh -v pi 192.168.1.1`

and that's where I'm stuck, I don't know what to do. I expect to just write:

`raspberry`

and it should answer like this:
look at the screenshot near/under 92.

[image]
Everything above is done on the Virtual machine.

Comment: Try `ssh pi@192.168.1.1` Are you sure your Pi's IP is 192.168.1.1?

Comment: eth1 gives me back with the ifconfig command that it is my IP address. It's my inet addr

Comment: On which device did you execute `eth0`?

Comment: @jrust The message `Permission denied, try again` not only means that the password you entered is wrong, but also that you are connected to your Pi. Do you have a keyboard layout different than QWERTY? If so, have a look to this [anwser](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4366/797).

Comment: In the virtual Debian box (in the virtual box program).

Comment: @MorganCourbet I use QWERTY.

Comment: @jrust Maybe you should first try to get rid of the VirtualBox part. Open a terminal in you Mac, run `ssh pi@192.168.1.1`, and enter `raspberry` as the password.

Comment: Still didn't get it. Do you try to connect to a Pi from a virtual machine on your Mac, or are you trying to connect from your mac to a virtual machine running raspbian?

Comment: @tmartin i'm trying to connect from a virtual machine on my mac to a raspberry pi. The virtual machine uses Debian as it's OS

Comment: Okay, then you'll have to find out the IP of your Pi. `eth0` on your virtual machine gives you back the IP of the virtual machine. Maybe you have access to your router and can find out the IP, otherwise you'll have to connect the Pi to display and keyboard.

Comment: @MorganCourbet i get this:  `connect to host 192.168.1.1 port 22: Operation timed out`

Comment: @tmartin eth0 address: `inet addr: 10.0.2.15`

Comment: Please join the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17434/using-a-ssh-and-cant-login-on-my-raspberry) as we, @tmartin and I, do not seem to understand well your problem.

Comment: @MorganCourbet I don't have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you have tried, what does not work, and what you expect. I think that what is difficult to understand is from which device you run the commands (your computer, the VirtualBox, and your RPi). The difficult part is the VB. Either get git of it (temporarily), or provide a clear schema where you make visible the interfaces and their IP.

Comment: @MorganCourbet I have updated my question

Comment: I think you missed the part where the RPi is involved ;-) Anyway, as @tmartin mentionned, are you sure the RPi IP address is 192.168.1.1? Is the RPi unique for the classroom, or you have your own? If it is common for the class, make sure one of your funny classmate didn't change the password :-D Maybe you should ask your teacher.

Comment: @MorganCourbet I'll ask him. Thanks for the help and support!

Comment: Oh, I don't know if you are familiar with SE.com, but you can answer your own question. Please leave your answer when you have the solution. Maybe it could help other people ;-)

Comment: I'll most certainly post my answer :)

Comment: @jrust Thanks for your edit. But this is... an answer :-) Could you please post it as an answer by clicking the _Post Your Answer_ button? Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the LAN connection can retrieve an IP Address (192.168.1.1). You have to turn IPv4 off in settings (for@jrust, check iArch_week3 @87) , so the virtual machine gives the Raspberry its own IP, in our case 192.168.1.100.

In Windows, we have to turn off IPv4 and v6 in order to ssh into our Raspberry.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 3):

First of all 192.168.1.1 is very likely not to be the pi's IP address but the one of your router. So, if you have access to the Pi then in terminal type "hostname -I" and the ip returned should probably have a two or three digit number at the end something like 192.168.1.10 or 192.168.1.100 this is the IP address you should put into the terminal on the Mac ssh pi@the-pi's-ip

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

At least you have given some detail, but what you are trying just introduces too much complication.

You should try (from a terminal on the Mac):-
`ssh pi@IPaddress`

It is almost certain that the Pi's address is NOT `192.168.1.1`, as this is most likely the gateway. You can check this by typing `netstat -nr`(in a terminal on the Mac).

If the Mac (is it yours or shared) has `nmap` installed `nmap -sP 192.168.1.*` would show all the active addresses on your network.